# What is causing a segmentation fault in this function?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

So, as an exercise, I am developing a code that uses a recursive function in order to make a simple mathematical expressions calculator. The problem is, I am getting a segmentation fault (6) or (11) when I run it, but I have checked a hundred times and each function call seems to be accessing memory only from the variables in the function just above it on the stack, provided by the pointer *init. Where am I getting this wrong?

Code is as follows:

```
int solve(char *expression, int *init) {

  int result;
  int l = strlen(expression);
  int i = *init;

  //Inicializing result:
  for (int n = 0; n <= l; n++) {
    if ((expression[n]=='1')||(expression[n]=='2')||(expression[n]=='3')||(expression[n]=='4')||(expression[n]=='5')||
    (expression[n]=='6')||(expression[n]=='7')||(expression[n]=='8')||(expression[n]=='9')) {
        result = expression[n]-48;
        break;
    }
  }

//Doing calculations:
  int j = i;
  for (j; j <= l; j++) {
    if (expression[j] == '(') {
      result = result + solve(expression, &j);
    }
    if (expression[j] == '+')
      result = result + (expression[j+1]-48);
    if (expression[j] == '-')
      result = result - (expression[j+1]-48);
    if (expression[j] == '*')
      result = result * (expression[j+1]-48);
    if (expression[j] == '/')
      result = result / (expression[j+1]-48);
    if (expression[j] == ')')
      return result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: With the loop condition `n <= l` you *will* go out of bounds. Then in the second loop where you use `j + 1` you will go out of bounds even more.

Comment: On what line does the segfault occur?

Comment: How are you calling `solve()`?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: `result = expression[n]-48;` should use `'0'` in place of `48`. There's a function/macro `isdigit()` in `<ctype.h>` that tests more efficiently.  The digits are required to be in a contiguous range of code points; you could use `expression[n] >= '0' && expression[n] <= '9')`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why is `expression[strlen(expression)]` out of bounds?

Comment: @Ctx The standard defines the length of a string -- it does not include the null byte (it's the opening sentence or two of section 7.1.1 of the standard). I partially misread your comment, but be cautious.  I'll clean up comments on this momentarily.:

Comment: Your code has little or no protection against error.  You should show some sample input that crashes your code; that's a part of producing an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Your segfault occurs, because you recurse too deep on an opening parenthesis. You don't need ´itit` to be a pointer -- you never assign anything back anyway. The first loop should probably start from `i` or `init`. More likely, it shouldn't be a loop at all.

Comment: @Ctx For any array, what are the valid indexes? For any string the valid indexes are `0` to `strlen(...) - 1`. Well *technically* it's not really out of bounds (should not be anyway), since `strlen(...)` will be the index of the *terminator* but it's out of bounds of the actual contents of the string.

Comment: Unrelated to the question and your problem, but very much related to the code itself: Don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character `'0'` then use the actual character. It makes your code clearer, and in the case of digits more portable (there exists systems which don't use ASCII).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would take a different perspective: valid indexes on a string do not exist at all, since a string is not really a datatype, but a _convention_ in c. Only indexes on arrays exist, and an array holding a string is _at least_ of size `strlen(s)+1` (i.e. when initialized with `char foo[] = "bar";`, sizeof(foo) will be 4). But yes, seeing it an informal way, foo[strlen(foo)] can be interpreted as "outside the string", depending on if one counts the terminating zero byte as _part_ of the string or not.

Answer (score 2):

**There is infinite recursion in the code**

```
int solve(char *expression, int *init) {
  /* ... */
  int j = i;
  for (j; j <= l; j++) {
    if (expression[j] == '(') {
      result = result + solve(expression, &j);
  /* ... */
```

If it ever founds a `'('` in `expression`, then the function is called over and over again with the same parameters, until the program stack is filled up. Then you get a segfault.

**When using loops or recursion, you should always make sure that the construct eventually terminates**, i.e. it gets demonstrably closer to the terminating condition on every iteration. It's trivial to see when doing a simple loop like `for(i=0;i<x;i++)`, but considerably harder when the iteration and the terminating conditions are scattered over a recursive function.

It's not the only problem with your code, but arguably the most severe one.